# Chef to pull from local directory

Tags: chef-infra

Usually Chef client in chef node pulls from chef server which has the changes. How do I point chef client to a local folder which has my changes. Will Chef Solo help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. We can use `chef-solo` to have cookbooks locally and execute them directly on the nodes.

Let's take an example node `node1.example.net`, we can have a config file in it `solo.rb` (can be any name).

**solo.rb**

```rb
cookbook_path '/home/user/.chef/cookbooks'
file_cache_path '/home/user/.chef/cache'
role_path '/home/user/.chef/roles'
data_bag_path '/home/user/.chef/databags'
```

If we run `chef-solo` at this point

```
chef-solo -c /home/user/.chef/solo.rb
```

There will no `run_list` so nothing will happen, but a `<node name>.json` will be created in the `.chef/nodes` directory, like `node1.example.net.json`.

Now we can store the cookbooks under `/home/user/.chef/cookbooks`, and add the appropriate cookbooks in the `run_list` of the `node1.example.net.json` file.

Or we can supply an optional `.json` file with the runlist we need. Something like `example.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "tftest-devops01.headquarters.healthedge.com",
  "chef_environment": "_default",
  "json_class": "Chef::Node",
  // some lines removed
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[my_cookbook]"
  ]
}
```

Then run as:

```
chef-solo -c solo.rb -j example.json
```

**chef-zero**

There is also a [chef-zero](https://github.com/chef/chef-zero), which can help run a "local" (in-memory) Chef server to mimic Chef server functionality allowing us to perform `knife` operations.

Comment: Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: base

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* base. This error has popped up now

Comment: Do you have all the cookbooks in `cookbook_path`? If you are working with cookbooks with several dependencies, then you should have all of them (and their versions) in that path.