# Execution Chef Cookbook using chef-solo

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-zero

I am trying to execute chef solo on my windows vm locally using Powershell. (I am trying to execute cookbook during provisioning customise Windows VM on cloud)
All cookbook recipe dependencies are available within the cookbook.

Create **solo.rb** for recipe execution & **web.json** to run recipe.

```
"type": "powershell",
"inline": "chef-client --chef-license=accept -z -o cookbooks\\cookbook_workstation"
```

*Error:*

- WARN: Failed to read the private key C:\chef\client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:\chef\client.pem>
- WARN: Error while reporting run start to Data Collector. URL: https://localhost:443/data-collector Exception: No HTTP Code -- I cannot read C:\chef\client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
- FATAL: NoMethodError: undefined method `logger' for nil:NilClass <internal:warning>:43:in` warn': warning: Chef::Compliance::Runner#logger at C:/opscode/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:154 forwarding to private method NilClass#logger (StructuredWarnings::BuiltInWarning)

Using chef-solo so I don't need chef server - how can I overcome client.pem WARN and logger issue. Pointers would be very helpful

Comment: `chef-solo` is an executable like `chef-client`. Shouldn't you be running `chef-solo --chef-license=accept ...`?

Comment: Error messages are pretty clear, did you create the pem file?  Where did you store it?

Comment: @Colyn1337: I haven't created .pem file (i am already using cookbook which was working in windows 2016) - Do i need to create .pem file ? if yes, how do i create it - please suggest

Comment: I am new to chef CM.
I am running chef client in local-mode, do i need to create client.pem file or do I need client.pem file at all ?

Comment: There is a difference between running `chef-solo` and `chef-client -z` (Chef zero). Also Chef Client/Solo requires elevated privileges. See if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64982763/13968097) helps.

Comment: @seshadri_c there's no difference between chef-solo and chef-client -z since chef 12 I think, chef-solo run in zero mode unless you use the --legacy-mode (which was removed in chef14), so in recent version (16 I guess from ruby version and need to accept the license) those commands are the same. I'd be curious about what is in solo.rb as configuration as I guess the problem is here, zero mode should create the file itself.